# lowest and highest from text file - python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and I am having a problem with my code I get the wrong data printed in my output as my date, year,  lowest, and highest temperature. I am not sure what changes I need to make in my code to print the correct lowest and highest temp from the text file. Thanks for the help.

Here is how my output for the code below looks like:

Day:  02/01
Year:  2002
The lowest temp is:  8
Day:  02/06
Year:  2008
The highest temp is:  77

```
def main():


file = open ('open_File.txt', 'r')

lowest = 200
lowest_day = ""
lowest_year = ""
highest = 0
highest_day = ""
highest_year = ""



for line in file.read().splitlines():
        if line[0].isdigit():
            values = line.strip().split()
            low = (values[3])
            high = (values[1])

            for lowest in low:
                if low < lowest:
                    lowest = low
                    lowest_day = values[0]
                    lowest_year = values[2]



            for highest in high:
                if high > highest:
                    highest = high
                    highest_day = values[0]
                    highest_year = values[2]




print ("Day: ", (lowest_day))
print ("Year: ", (lowest_year))
print ("The lowest temperature is: ", (lowest))


print ("Day: ", (highest_day))
print ("Year: ", (highest_year))
print ("The highest temperature is: ", (highest))
```

main()

This is a sample of how my file looks like. (I only included the columns I need from the text file)

```
Day     Max   Year   Min    
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
02/01   79   2002    8  
02/02   69   1989    5  
02/03   83   1989    7  
02/04   76   1957    3  
02/05   98   1890    0  
02/06   77   2008    9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
file = open('text.txt', 'r')

lowest = 200
lowest_day = 0
lowest_year = 0
highest = 0
highest_day = 0
highest_year = 0


for line in file.read().splitlines():
    if line[0].isdigit():
        values = line.strip().split()
        low = int(values[3])
        high = int(values[1])

        if low < lowest:
            lowest = low
            lowest_day = values[0]
            lowest_year = values[2]

        if high > highest:
            highest = high
            highest_day = values[0]
            highest_year = values[2]

print ("Day: ", (lowest_day))
print ("Year: ", (lowest_year))
print ("The lowest temperature is: ", (lowest))


print ("Day: ", (highest_day))
print ("Year: ", (highest_year))
print ("The highest temperature is: ", (highest))
```

This gives the output:

```
Day:  02/05
Year:  1890
The lowest temperature is:  0
Day:  02/05
Year:  1890
The highest temperature is:  98
```

Some notes: `for lowest in low:` doesn't make sense as `low` is just a single character, and not a list or something, so I removed it. Also, you were comparing integers with strings, so I converted the strings to integers.

Comment: Sure, if it worked for you please mark as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because you have two variables named lowest (and two called highest). When you create the loop

```
for lowest in low:
```

Python iterates through the characters in "low" and compares if they are less than "low" (which makes no sense). The variable "lowest" has been overwritten by this for loop, and so the program gives erroneous results. Also, in order to find the lowest temperature, the data being compared to the lowest value must be a numeric data type, and not string type.

To resolve this, you should do away with the "for lowest in low line", and simply create a variable (e.g. lineLow) for the minimum temperature each day. This variable would be equal to

```
int(values[3])
```

The same is applicable for the higher temperature.

(Also, instead of file.read().splitlines(), you can use file.readlines())

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more pythonic way then I think the following code might help as well.

```
file = open ('temp.txt', 'r')

myfunc1= lambda s: s[3]
myfunc2= lambda s: s[1]

lines = [line.strip().split() for line in file.read().splitlines() if line[0].isdigit()]

lowest= sorted(lines, key=myfunc1)[0]
highest = sorted(lines, key=myfunc2, reverse=True)[0]

print("lowestDAY: {0}, lowestYear: {1}, lowestTemp: {2}".format(lowest[0], lowest[2], lowest[3]))
print("highestDAY: {0}, highestYear: {1}, highestTemp: {2}".format(highest[0], highest[2], highest[1]))
```